# How does Firebase analytics iOS SDK track screens?

Tags: ios, firebase-analytics

I am implementing a logging module for my project. One of the feature is to track screens(or viewController) transitions. One obvious approach is to add tracking code in viewDidAppear (and viewDidDisappear) of every view controller I have. However, I do not want to pollute my code with all these tracking code. It seems Firebase analytics has solved this problem. It automatically tracks all view controller without me having to add any code. The problem is I do not know how they did it. Could anyone shed a light?

Comment: Have you found anything?